# how to convert png image to vectorized image?

Tags: android, image, svg, vector

I use this online converter and more than this 
https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg to convert image to vector but i only can get image as svg icon and its tag is svg but i need to make its tag vector like  this format

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/redtext"
    android:pathData="M12,21.35l-1.45,-1.32C5.4,15.36 2,12.28 2,8.5 2,5.42 4.42,3 7.5,3c1.74,0 3.41,0.81 4.5,2.09C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3 19.58,3 22,5.42 22,8.5c0,3.78 -3.4,6.86 -8.55,11.54L12,21.35z"/>
```

so how can i get image with this format and make it vector image .I also try with illustrator but also I get svg only .I need image for android app.

Answer (score 3):

Right click in the image folder (like drawable or mipmap) > `New` > `Vector Asset`

[image]

select the .svg file and set a name:

[image]

and the you will have created the vector drawable file:

[image]

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M21.71,11.29l-9,-9c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-9,9c-0.39,0.39 -0.39,1.02 0,1.41l9,9c0.39,0.39 1.02,0.39 1.41,0l9,-9c0.39,-0.38 0.39,-1.01 0,-1.41zM14,14.5V12h-4v3H8v-4c0,-0.55 0.45,-1 1,-1h5V7.5l3.5,3.5 -3.5,3.5z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: is there are any methods to do this before i start in android .i need icon first to be like the format i wrote it before . I shouldn't do it with android